# Fill in the Blank String

Tags: java, c

I am studying for an interview and having trouble with this question.

Basically, you have a word that has spaces in it like c_t.

You have a word bank and have to find all the possible words that can be made with the given string. So for in this case, if cat was in the word bank we would return true.

Any help on solving this question (like an optimal algorithm would be appreciated).

I think we can start with checking lengths of strings in the word bank and then maybe use a hashmap somehow.

Comment: What is the code you have written so far?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, MCVE for short](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this, that is why I am asking. I want to solve it using a hashmap, but am not sure how to start.

Comment: You have marked this as "Java" and "C". Which language do you want?

Comment: More like an algorithm. Not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1.) Eliminate all words in the wordbook that don't have the same length as the specified one.

Step 2.) Eliminate all words in the bank that don't have the same starting sequence and ending sequence.

Step 3.) If the specified string is fragmented like `c_ter_il_ar`, for each word left in the bank check if it contains the isolated sequences at those exact same indexes such as `ter`  and `il` and eliminate those that don't have it

Step 4.) At this point all the words left in the bank are viable solutions, so return true if the bank is non-empty

Comment: This is a good algorithm. If someone has one that is more efficient, please post it.

Comment: Depending on the size of the word bank, it may end up being more efficient to impose all of these steps on each word sequentially, to reduce the time it takes to iterate through the list. Also, if the word bank is sorted, you can reduce read time even further using binary search algorithms

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what your interviewer is looking for... creativity, knowledge of algorithms, mastery of data structures?  One off-the-cuff solution would be to substitute underscores for any spaces and use a LIKE clause in a SQL query.

`SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word LIKE 'c_t';` should return "cat", "cot" and "cut".

If you're being evaluated on your ability to divide and conquer, then you should be able to reason whether it's more work to extract a list of candidate words and evaluate each against your criteria, or to generate a list of candidate words from your criteria and evaluate each against your dictionary.